Unable to run Playwright Typescript Bitbucket Pipeline
Version used: 1.49.0
Steps to reproduce
I have the following files:
bitbucket-pipelines.yml

Ubuntu Pastebin
package.json

Ubuntu Pastebin
package.lock.json

Ubuntu Pastebin
Expected behavior
It should successfully run the pipeline.
Actual behavior
When I try to run the pipeline, I get this error:
Ubuntu Pastebin
Please suggest how to resolve this.
I tried several different images, but it's not working.
Thank you for your time.
Environment
bitbucket-pipelines.yml
[Ubuntu Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9GvMzTCj3x/)

package.json
[Ubuntu Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/X8YHH9rScF/)

package.lock.json
[Ubuntu Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GJMZr6b6t7/)

